# SQL Server ::FN_LISTEXTENDEDPROPERTY to SAP HANA

Tags: sql-server, hana

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(255), VALUE) 
FROM ::FN_LISTEXTENDEDPROPERTY (DEFAULT, 'USER', 'DBO', 'TABLE','Accounts', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

I need a equivalent SAP HANA query for the above SQL query.

Comment: That's a very specific SQL Server query. It's quite possible that SAP Hana doesn't even have some of the objects this query is referring to: extended properties, a dbo schema. What is the real purpose of this? You would need to put the extended properties into SAP Hana before a converted query could pull them out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By querying Extended Properties for a database object, users can reaad user defined key-value pairs

For example, I have defined a few key value pairs in properties screen of a database table as follows

[image]

And it is possible to query this data as follows,

```
SELECT convert(varchar(255), VALUE) 
FROM ::FN_LISTEXTENDEDPROPERTY ('Client', 'USER', 'DBO', 'TABLE','SD', DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
```

The output will be "060" for the execution of above T-SQL statement

There is a simple Properties screen on SAP HANA Studio but does not let the user add new values unfortunately